# the placement of adverbials

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the position of the adverbial YESTERDAY in the sentence below correct or not?

> She told me **yesterday** that she had been to Russia three times before.

If there are better placements, share it please.

Comment: You could also begin the sentence with **yesterday**. But it's just an alternative, not an improvement.

Comment: so my sentence is correct??

Comment: Perfectly correct. I wonder only what you imply by **before**. That's to say, before what? What information does **before** add to the sentence. I'm not certain that it adds any, unless you are suggesting that the scene is taking place in Russia on her fourth visit.

Comment: @OsamaFeras Yes, your sentence is grammatically fine and semantically unambiguous. The _that_ clause functions as complement of "told".

Comment: Please be aware that unless she is in Russia right now, (the 4th time), before would be incorrect.

Comment: @Lambie If she'd *ever* been to Russia 4 times, and the context of the conversation was the 4th time, then this sentence would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

> She told me **yesterday** that she had been to Russia three times before.

is fine.

---

You can use different word order:

> **Yesterday**, she told me that she had been to Russia three times before.

Answer (score -3):

No one can say: "*It is grammatically incorrect.*", however, we can discuss its level of accuracy.

"*Yesterday*" is an adverb expressing when the action was performed, which means that it is not a verb complement, but it is just an extra information.

"*That she had been to Russia three times before*" is a noun clause functioning as a direct object/verb complement.

Finally, the question here is "*Which one should be closer to the verb tell* ?"

The answer is the direct object "that ...."

The best way is:

> **Yesterday**, she told me that she had been to Russia three times before.

Your sentence is grammatically neither **wrong** nor **perfect**.

Comment: You are on dangerous ground when you declare which sentences are perfect and which imperfect.

Comment: Anyone familiar enough with English can say a given sentence is "grammatically incorrect".